# omniauth-stripe-connect refresh_token for test mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth, stripe-payments

Currently using Rails 4, Omniauth, and Omniauth-Stripe-Connect.

I need the refresh token to generate test keys for users but it's no where to be found in the raw data that's returned? Looked through issues/threads/etc no one mentions this issue or even any details on doing test mode with stripe connect beyond the couple lines in stripe docs here (but can't do this because refresh_token is missing):

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth#test-keys-for-livemode-applications

Answer (score 0):

Pull from the git repo directly 

`gem 'omniauth-stripe-connect', :git => 'git@github.com:isaacsanders/omniauth-stripe-connect.git'`